# Plotting pdf in python

Tags: python, plot, data-science

I have two list **A = [0.5,0.34.75 .... 1]** and **B = [0.52,0.44,0.75 ....,0.9]**.

The length of **A** and **B** is different.  The values of **A** and **B** are between **0** and **1**. I tried to generate their PDFs (Probability Distribution Functions) in same figure in the following way:

```
x = pd.Series(A, name="x variable")
y = pd.Series(B, name="x variable")
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': x,
    'B': y,
})
ax = df.plot.kde()
```

However it does not generate pdf. How can i generate pdf?

Edit: I want to generate two pdf curves in the same figure. I found this way to do that in an online tutorial but i don't know the distribution of the data so i can't simply chose random normal distribution or any other distribution.

(1): I have no idea how to estimate the pdf.

(2): it generates following results which are not pdfs.

(3): On x-axis i want number and on y-axis i want probability.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify; how does this generate a PDF?  I suspect that you mean a "PANDAS data frame" rather than the common file format.

Comment: Please fill this out to the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: There are many sources for plotting data with different lengths.  Please focus your post to one issue: is your failure in creating the staggered data frame, or in plotting the result?

Comment: @Prune i edited the post. Any help would be great as i am new to data science. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code example you're using [KDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation), thus non-parametric estimation of the probability density function, which i'm assuming you mean by PDF, using Gaussian kernel.

Pandas `kde` function allows to choose bandwidth method and evaluation points, both [by parameters](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.kde.html).

Pandas actually uses the SciPy implementation of kde, please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html#scipy.stats.gaussian_kde) to better understand the implementation and how to choose parameters .